# How can I remove an element from a list by index, when the index matches a value from another list?

Tags: r, list, indexing

I have a list (list_a) with values and I want to remove all values from that list that have a certain index. To do this I already have a separate list (list_b) that has all the indexes that I want to remove as its values. Now I want to remove from list_a all the values that have an index that matches a value from list_b.

To make it easy to understand here is an example:

```
list_a <- list("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five") # original list

list_b <- list(2, 4) # indexes that I want to remove from list_a

# Desired Output:
# [1] "One" "Three" "Five"
```

I tried doing the following:

```
list_c <- list_a[-c(list_b)]
# But got the following error:
# Error : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Because I know that I can remove the indexes in the following manner:

```
list_c <- list_a[-c(2,4)]
```

But I don't want to know the values that I want to remove beforehand, can't I use a list as an argument to remove indexes of another list?

Comment: Index values must be a vector, not a list so `unlist(list_a[-unlist(list_b)])` will get you want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t index using a list; you need to use an [atomic vector](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#vector-basics). You can solve your issue by

1. Creating `list_b` as a numeric vector to begin with:

```
list_b <- c(2, 4)
list_a[list_b]
```

2. Or converting to an atomic vector using `as.numeric()` or [`unlist()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/unlist).

```
# either
list_a[as.numeric(list_b)]
# or
list_a[unlist(list_b)]
```